# how do I change entry from draft to live?

Tags: draft

I have an entry showing as draft but I would like it to go live. I have looked but can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

An unpublished draft will show a button `Create entry` at the upper right, this will create a published entry from the draft:

[image: a screenshot of the action buttons on the entry editing forms]

If you're not seeing this button, you probably don't have the required permission. You need the `Save entries` permissions for the section that your entry belongs to in order to publish drafts.

Comment: Just adding that there's an additional grey button that says "Apply Draft" if you're inside a draft version of an existing entry. 

The Red "Create Entry" is just when its an unpublished first draft.